# I have an area on which i have to draw something like signature how can i do this in appium version 1.15 java,Image link is attached

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have an area on which i have to draw something like signature how can I do this in appium version 1.15  java,Image link is attached.

I have tried actions and Touch Actions but it does not worked.

```
TouchActions action= new TouchActions(driver)
                .longPress((WebElement) PointOption.point(464, 727)).(PointOption.point(977, 7)).release().perform();
```

**Image of signature location**

[image: Image of Signature]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swipe left using -

```
Dimension size = appiumDriver.manage().window().getSize(); 
int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.8); 
int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.20); 
int starty = size.height / 2; 
appiumDriver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);
```

Swipe right-

```
appiumDriver.context("NATIVE_APP"); 
Dimension size = appiumDriver.manage().window().getSize(); 
int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.8); 
int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.20); 
int starty = size.height / 2; 
appiumDriver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);
```

OR

`new TouchAction(driver).longPress(250, 1200).moveTo(900, 1200).release().perform();`